# dropzone pause file uploading when javascript confirmation prompt out

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

Is that any function to pause the file upload of a specific file when javascript confirmation prompt out?
I want to develop using dropzone.js so that when user click "cancel" button, a javascript confirmation will prompt so i am expecting the script will pause the specific file upload until the user confirm if proceed to cancel the uploading or proceed with the uploading.

any event or function to use?

I also asked the same question here, https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/issues/750